# 'extension' in namespace 'cocos2d' does not name a type

Tags: android, build, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a game project now using cocos2dx ver3.0, and now, I'm stuck with this error:

```
'extension' in namespace 'cocos2d' does not name a type
```

This error appear when building source code, as I know so far, extension will be configured in Android.mk as you see below:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/extensions

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static
```

So why the compiler prompted me that message, plz give me a help.
This is total stack trace:

```
In file included from jni/../../Classes/views/include/../scene/GameScene.h:9:0,
             from jni/../../Classes/views/include/views.h:4,
             from jni/../../Classes/BusinessHandler.h:6,
             from jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:2:
jni/../../Classes/views/include/../scene/../layer/InventoryLayer.h:29:5: error: 'extension' in namespace 'cocos2d' does not name a type
 cocos2d::extension::ScrollView* checkContentScrollView;
 ^
```

Comment: Have you include "cocos-ext.h"?

Comment: Thank Laurent very much, it worked